# Powerpoint 2010 - PDF Export stops some hyperlinks from working

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, hyperlink

When we create a Power Point Presentation and link shapes to slides (as a way of navigating), I've noticed that if we then export the file to PDF some of the shapes no longer hold their hyperlinks to the slides we set.

I've tried this across 3 different PC's Win7, & Win 8.1 all using Office 2010 Pro (Latest updates for office and windows all up to date on updates as well), with the same results each time.

From my testing so far it appears as though basic shapes that do not have any sort of effects applied to them (3D etc) hold onto their links, whereas shapes that have 3D effects or other styles seem to be affected and no longer link.

It seems to me as though this behaviour is down to the PDF Conversion process, I've tried changing a range of different settings within the Advanced button of the Save As PDF Dialog in Power Point with no change in the output.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if you get better results by doing a conversion to pdf with non-Office software, for example Cloud Convert: https://cloudconvert.com/ppt-to-pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further results:

The links work in PPT itself.

With PPT's Save As | Type of File:  PDF conversion, the links are simply not there.

With Adobe's Save As PDF feature, the links are there but point to the first slide in the presentation (or perhaps to the slide that the linked shapes are on ... not sure which).  NOT to the right location though.

Definitely buggy in both PPT and in Adobe's add-in.

FWIW:  I have a commercial add-in (PPTools Prep4PDF) that I wrote back before PPT made its own PDFs and when Adobe's own add-in sorta sucked.  I keep thinking I'll retire it one of these days, but I keep finding new uses for the thing.  This is another.  Seems the links work correctly when I use Prep4PDF to convert the test presentation.

[and a bit later]

The same links DO work correctly using PPT's Save As | File Type: PDF feature from PowerPoint 2013.

Comment: thanks for check In PowerPoint 2013, it would appear as though its down to the conversion of the document in PowerPoint, I've now gone and installed a freeware PDf converter which resolved the issue.